# Implementing a MediaBrowserServiceCompat in a HeadlessJsTaskService

Tags: android, react-native, service, exoplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

I'm working on a music player in my React Native app. I have a fully functioning player right now based on ExoPlayer 2.17.1 that is controlled by a `MusicService` class extending `HeadlessJsTaskService()`.

The issue is that now I need to support **Android Auto** and to do that you need a MediaBrowserService registered per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#implement_browser).

**Is there any way for me to extend both of these services?** The headless ability is critical to a smooth running player in React Native, so my last resort would be to ditch that all together and implement a standard Android `MediaBrowserServiceCompat()`

Here are some snippets from my project:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<!-- The main service, handles playback, playlists and media buttons -->
<service android:name=".audio.service.MusicService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**MusicService.kt**

```
class MusicService : HeadlessJsTaskService() {
    private lateinit var player: BaseAudioPlayer // My ExoPlayer controller
```

Comment: any luck on this implementation ?

Comment: Sadly no. I had submit a request on react-native-track-player's repo to see what they thought and it didn't really go anywhere. For now we've just implemented a regular `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` and it works well enough with events passing data back to RN. For AA, we had to basically make the native code perform all the network operations natively so that it didn't need RN at all.